# C++ function not a member of class with shared_ptr, or why is my variable undeclared?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class that is in the beginning stages of representing a dictionary and having some problems compiling. Aside from the file containing main, these are the only files in the project. Main contains no references to the Dictionary yet.

Dictionary.h

```
#include <vector>

typedef shared_ptr<Node> node_ptr;
struct Node;

class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary(void);
    ~Dictionary(void);
    Dictionary(char* filename);

private:
    node_ptr root;
    shared_ptr<Node> curNode;  // 3 
    void buildTree(char* filename);
    shared_ptr<Node> findChild(shared_ptr<Node> node, char val); // 1
    node_ptr findChild(node_ptr node, char val); // 2 (not repeated in actual header)
};
```

Dictionary.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include "Dictionary.h"

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node::Node(char val)
    {
        value = val;
    };
    vector<node_ptr> children;
    char value;
};

Dictionary::Dictionary(char* filename)
{
    root = make_shared<Node>(0);
    curNode = root;
    buildTree(filename);
}

Dictionary::Dictionary(){}
Dictionary::~Dictionary(void){}

shared_ptr<Node> Dictionary::findChild(shared_ptr<Node> node, char val)  // 1
node_ptr Dictionary::findChild(node_ptr node, char val)  // 2
{

    for(int i = 0; i < node->children.size(); i++)
    {
        if( node->children[i]->value == val )
            return node->children[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

void Dictionary::buildTree(char* filename)
{
    ifstream input;
    node_ptr temp;
    input.open(filename);
    char* line = (char*)malloc(45);

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)  //build the first 26 nodes
        root->children.push_back(make_shared<Node>('a' + i));

    while(!input.eof())
    {
        input >> line;
        int lind = 1;
        char curChar = line[0];
        curNode = findChild(root, curChar); //assume we got this one

        while(1)
        {
            curChar = line[lind];
            if(curChar == 0)
                break;

            temp = findChild(curNode, line[lind]);
            if(temp == 0)
            {
                temp = make_shared<Node>(line[lind]);
                curNode->children.push_back(temp);
                curNode = temp;
            }
            else
                curNode = temp;

            lind++;
        }
    }

    free(line);
}
```

When I compile this I get these errors.
In the case when bolded line 1 is used: " 'findChild : is not a member of 'Dictionary' "
In the case when bolded line 2 is used: " Syntax error : ')' "

On top of this I get errors claiming that my variables aren't declared such as curNode in Dictionary's constructor.

The issue seems to be around the use of shared_ptr somehow.

Comment: Removed. Haven't posted before and that was added by the Bold button.

Comment: Don't you need `std::shared_ptr` in dictionary.h instead of just `shared_ptr`?

Comment: That's it. Thank you! I knew it was going to be something obvious. How do I mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef shared_ptr<Node> node_ptr;
struct Node;
```

When you forward declare you need to declare before use, not the other way around. If you are not getting compilation error, it looks like you have `Node` defined somewhere else and `shared_ptr<Node>` means something different than your `typedef`, hence the error. It is difficult to say more as you do not provide MCVE.

Comment: Switched those around, but didn't change the errors. What you are looking at is all the code except for an empty main().

Comment: @danielm2100 attach exact errors from compiler to your question (if there are too many several ones form the beginning)

Answer (score -1):

Specifying a return type as "**shared_ptr" is giving you an error because that is not valid C++. It seems that you want "shared_ptr" since you are not dereferencing it (unless you are using that as a marker for readers).

Also, in the header you are specifying "shared_ptr" without "using namespace std;" above it, making the compiler think it is a global type when it in fact belongs to the "std" namespace.

Comment: I'm confused, why was this downvoted if the second part was the answer?

Comment: Probably because you should NEVER, EVER put `using <namespace>;` in header files.